# Would final users have to download iOS app again when app is moved from a Itunes Apple store account to another?

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

Suppose you have an iOS application associated to some account in Apple Store. Then, this account's onwer decide to disassociate such app from his/her account. So, I would have to upload (don't know for sure) this app to Apple Store again using a new account owner.

Would end users have to download app again (from this new account)? Or app updates would still work 'automatically'?

Regards,

Comment: Is that a individual apple developer account or a enterprise developer account?

Comment: There is a procedure on iTunes connect where you can transfer an app from one account to another. You have to contact Apple for that if I remember correctly. It's completely transparent for users, they will not have to redownload anything. Actually, they will probably never know.